# Gorm Rest Client for Grails 2.4.x and Grails 3.x.x

Tags: rest, grails, grails-orm

We have been using the gorm rest client (https://grails.org/plugin/gorm-rest-client) in our application on Grails v2.3.11.
I have attempted an update to Grails 2.4.4 but the plugin will fail at the startup with the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/grails/databinding/converters/CurrencyValueConverter
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.databinding.DataBindingGrailsPlugin$_closure1.doCall(DataBindingGrailsPlugin.groovy:101)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.databinding.DataBindingGrailsPlugin$_closure1.doCall(DataBindingGrailsPlugin.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:417)
at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:754)
at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:584)
at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:527)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithRuntimeConfiguration(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:511)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.doRuntimeConfiguration(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:123)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:154)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:126)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoaderListener.java:109)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What are the plans for keeping the plugin compatible with 2.4.x and 3.x.x?

Thanks

Comment: It's not compatible with 2.4 or 3.x and it appears to be abandoned. I have discussed this on the grails dev mailing list. I know, it's a shame. But, if someone takes over the plugin and fixes it for 2.4.x and 3.x that would be great. (Note I am not the author of the plugin, just someone who wanted to use it in 2.4.x)

Comment: Will revisit this plugin after Grails 3.0 is out, in the meantime contributions welcome